# Do we have to synthesize UIImageView and UIBUtton in any simple UITouch program?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, uitouch

Do we have to synthesize UIImageView and UIButton in any simple UITouch program? I googled but could not find any relevant any clear answer.

Comment: Please do not edit your question to add a completely new question on a different topic. Instead, ask a new question using the **Ask Question** button. Try to imagine someone searching this site in the future for an answer to your second question: they would never think to look at a question that asked about synthesizing controls. In addition, a separate question allows you to accept a separate answer, which is what this site is all about.

Comment: My fault. sorry. I'll make all new query for my question. Apology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We synthesize the properties. if we declare any variable, object and IBOutlet as property then we definitely need to synthesize it.

Make this as your practice, this is a good practice follow these step

- declare your UIControl
- Make IBOutlet
- Make property
- Make connections
- Synthesize it in .m
- set nil in `viewDidUnload`
- release it `dealloc`.

Comment: BTW, if you are just using a `UIButton` to trigger an action you don't actually have to declare it, just drag the button into place and then control drag from it to the controller and connect the action. YOu only need to declare the button if you plan to make changes to it at some point (like changing the title or perhaps disabling or enabling it)

Comment: @theMikeSWan Yap right brother. @krishnachandra in case button we dont need to do this untill we dont need to access it View related work.

Comment: Thank you buddies. Thats what i was searching for. Thank you . Now i'm clear.

One more thing. I'm trying to move to UIImageViews suing UITouch.
I've 2 imageViews say image1 and image2. I've these declared in .h file as UIIMageView *image1; UIImageView *image2;

NOw in the touchesBegan method, to drag an imageView, i used if condition as follows

     if([touch view] = image1){}

Comment: your code is correct carry on.declared image view as property and synthesize it.

Comment: I removed the second question. Please use the **Ask Question** button to ask about a completely different thing.

Comment: Done. I asked a new question.